# Find next smaller and next larger values

Tags: r, numbers, closest

I have two vectors:

`smaller_array <- c(50,  60,  70,  75,  80,  85,  90,  95, 100, 105)`

```
moneyness_cert <- c(105.8138,   105.7155,   105.4637,   104.5942,   105.0757,   105.316,    104.641,     
                    105.0637,   105.461,    104.971,    105.2471,   105.1348,   105.638,    105.8024,                                                               
                    105.592,    104.9338,   105.0133,   104.613,    104.9407,   105.0136,   107.2144,    
                    107.0112,   105.7793,   106.4742,   105.5703,   106.0615,   106.3446,   105.7296,    
                    105.1307,   104.6472,   103.6721,   104.607,    105.1265,   105.2077,   104.363,     
                    104.5036,   104.2205,   104.9135,   103.8404,   105.1506,   105.8887,   105.0894,    
                    104.3529,   103.0007,   103.0904,   103.334,    103.2959,   103.4819,   103.504,     
                    102.7641,   102.5911,   102.5386,   102.843,    103.8211,   102.3814,   105.265,     
                    104.3255,   104.1589,   105.6462,   107.0716,   106.5527,   104.655,    103.1285,    
                    102.3955,   102.8577) #length of vector is 65
```

I want to find for every moneyness_cert value the value which is closest to it in smaller_array.
The so found values should be saved in a vector (e.g. "result_vector")

Example for the 64th element in moneyness_cert:
moneyness_cert = 102.3955

then return in smaller_array the value "100"
and save it in result_vector at place 64

I tried (which returned unuseful results); match.closest-function from MALDIquant-Package:

```
>     match.closest(x = moneyness_cert, table = sort(smaller_array, decreasing = F), tolerance = Inf, nomatch = NA)
 [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
[26] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
[51] 10 10 10 10  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  9 10
```

Another try was:

```
> apply(smaller_array, 1 , function(x) moneyness_cert - x)
Error in apply(smaller_array, 1, function(x) moneyness_cert - x) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Via lapply it didn't work either.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sapply(moneyness_cert, function(x) smaller_array[which.min(abs(smaller_array - x))])
```

Output:

```
[1] 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105
[34] 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 100 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 105 100 105
```

Or directly for the 64th element:

```
sapply(moneyness_cert, function(x) smaller_array[which.min(abs(smaller_array - x))])[64]

# [1] 100
```

Comment: Hi arg0naut91, if I try to run your function it returns the error:  ``` >   money_closest_smaller <- sapply(moneyness_cert, function(x) smaller_array[which.min(abs(smaller_array - x))])    
Warning message:
In `-.default`(smaller_array, x) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.```

Comment: Hm, strange - it works with your example - can you re-check if the example you've posted corresponds to what you are working with?

Comment: moneyness_cert was formatted as xts-element. I converted it into numeric, now it works :). Thank you for your help! Best from Bavaria.

Answer (score 0):

using the same `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map_dbl(moneyness_cert, ~ smaller_array[which.min(abs(smaller_array - .x))])
```